# How to encode this JSON value to an emoji in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON data of countries with its telephone code, name, flag etc. For the flag the data has the value in this format \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddfc, how do I decode this to an actual picture of the flag in C#. Here is the sample of the data -

```
 {
        "name": {
            "common": "Angola",
            "official": "Republic of Angola",
        },

        "idd": {
            "root": "+2",
            "suffixes": [
                "44"
            ]
        },
        "capital": [
            "Luanda"
        ],

        "flag": "\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf4",

    },
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would you be able to show an example. Also could you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize this JSON string directly to an object with a matching schema. Displaying flags requires a font that actually contains those flags. The Pirate flag ‍☠ ("\uD83C\uDFF4\u200D\u2620\uFE0F") is included in browser fonts, but the Angolan flag isn't. Same with Windows Terminal. I didn't paste an image in the sentence above, I pasted the glyph.

Using any online converter or `Paste Special \ Paste JSON as Classes` in Visual Studio you can get these classes :

```
public class Idd
{
    public string root { get; set; }
    public List<string> suffixes { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string common { get; set; }
    public string official { get; set; }
}

public class Flag
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Idd idd { get; set; }
    public List<string> capital { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON snippet is part of an array, so this should work:

```
var flags=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Flag[]>(json);
```

Comment: Is the last statement going to give me the actual glyph?

Comment: You already have the actual glyph. Whether you can display it as a flag depends on the font

Comment: My intent is to display the flag and country name as list in a combo box. Also not sure what you mean by it being dependent on the font.

Comment: Google `Flag emojis`. You'll see that only a few of the flags in *any* list are visible. Which ones are visible depend on the platform (Windows, Mac, Linux) and the browser. In the [Emojipedia site](https://emojipedia.org/flags/) for example, on Windows I can only see the top 8 and bottom 1. On Android I can see all flags. [This article](https://blog.emojipedia.org/emoji-flags-explained/) explains why this happens. Flags are politically sensitive and only the 8 "neutral" emojis are actually required for interoperability

Comment: Think China and the Taiwanese flag for example.